# htacces to redirect to another page if the url contains 'manager'

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect the user based on the url they are using. Basically if the url    contains something like `www.my-domain.com/manager/` then redirect to `www.my-domain.com/admin/Login.php` . 
    If the url has "manager" with a trailing slash or without a trailing slash then redirect it to `www.my-domain.com/admin/Login.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^manager/$
RewriteRule .* admintti/Login.php
```

The above code I am trying but its of no use.
   Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'd post this as an answer, but really it's just basic troubleshooting: do you have other rewrites which are actually working? That is, have you confirmed that `mod_rewrite` is in place and there's a `RewriteEngine on` elsewhere in the config?

Comment: I have posted this as an answer pjmorse. Yes I have RewriteEngine in the htaccess. I am very weak related to htaccess. So it would be great if you direct me to the right path concerning the extra url as I have mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You don't really need `mod_rewrite` for this](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite).

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/manager(.+) /admintti/Login.php
```

Comment: Thanks pjmorse.. It is working fine.. but I am having another issue. After redirecting the url becomes "www.my-domain.com/admin/Login.php?url=/manager/&url=/manager" . Extra url=manager/&url=manager is getting attached. I dont need them.

Comment: @Yunus Do you have rewrite rules somewhere? if you do, mod_rewrite will clobber what mod_alias directives do (e.g. `RedirectMatch`)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule .*?manager.* admintti/Login.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You're matching against the `HTTP_HOST`, which doesn't contain any path info. you want to match where the `.*` is:

```
RewriteRule .*manager.* /admin/Login.php [L]
```